# WP Rewrite Rule Issue while using Custom post type & taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing shared by Milo in this post : [WP Rewrite Rules - Custom post type & taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144329/wp-rewrite-rules-custom-post-type-taxonomy/279921)

Everything works perfectly with pagination but i got a 404 while trying to acess to my single custom post type post.

To explain :

site.com/products = OK

site.com/products/page/2 = OK

site.com/products/category = OK

site.com/products/category/page/2 = OK

site.com/products/category/product-name = 404

Here is my code ($productCategoryBaseSlug is a php variable set somewhere else with a value of "products" in this example) :

```
/**** CUSTOM POST TYPE ****/

        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => __( 'Product', 'Post Type General Name', $this->text_domain ),
            'singular_name'         => __( 'Product', 'Post Type Singular Name', $this->text_domain ),
            'menu_name'             => __( 'Products', $this->text_domain ),
            'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Product', $this->text_domain ),
            'archives'              => __( 'Product Archives', $this->text_domain ),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Product:', $this->text_domain ),
            'all_items'             => __( 'All Products', $this->text_domain ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Product', $this->text_domain ),
            'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', $this->text_domain ),
            'new_item'              => __( 'New Product', $this->text_domain ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Product', $this->text_domain ),
            'update_item'           => __( 'Update Product', $this->text_domain ),
            'view_item'             => __( 'View Product', $this->text_domain ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search Product', $this->text_domain ),
            'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', $this->text_domain ),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', $this->text_domain ),
            'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', $this->text_domain ),
            'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', $this->text_domain ),
            'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', $this->text_domain ),
            'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', $this->text_domain ),
            'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into Product', $this->text_domain ),
            'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Product', $this->text_domain ),
            'items_list'            => __( 'Products list', $this->text_domain ),
            'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Products list navigation', $this->text_domain ),
            'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter Products list', $this->text_domain ),
        );
        $args = array(
            'label'                 => __( 'Product', $this->text_domain ),
            'description'           => __( 'Replacement for text post', $this->text_domain ),
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats', ),
            'taxonomies'            => array( 'product_category', 'brand'),
            'hierarchical'          => false,
            'public'                => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_in_menu'          => true,
            'menu_position'         => 5,
            'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
            'can_export'            => true,
            'has_archive'           => $productCategoryBaseSlug,        
            'exclude_from_search'   => false,
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'query_var'             => false,
            'capability_type'       => 'post',
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => $productCategoryBaseSlug.'%product_category%',
                'with_front' => false
            )        
        );
        register_post_type( 'product', $args );


/**** CUSTOM TAXONOMY ****/
        $genre_args = array( 
            'hierarchical' => true,  
            'labels' => array(
                'name'=> __('Categories', 'taxonomy general name', $this->text_domain),
                'singular_name' => __('Category', 'taxonomy singular name', $this->text_domain),
                'search_items' => __('Search Categories', $this->text_domain),
                'popular_items' => __('Popular Categories', $this->text_domain),
                'all_items' => __('All Categories', $this->text_domain),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Category', $this->text_domain),
                'update_item' => __('Update Category', $this->text_domain),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Category', $this->text_domain),
                'new_item_name' => __('New Category Name', $this->text_domain),
                'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Seperate Categories with Commas', $this->text_domain),
                'add_or_remove_items' => __('Add or Remove Categories', $this->text_domain),
                'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose from Most Used Categories', $this->text_domain)
            ),  
            'public' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'query_var' => true,  
            'rewrite' => array(
                'with_front' => false,
                'slug' => $productCategoryBaseSlug /*__( 'product_category', 'product-category', $this->text_domain )*/
            )        
        );
        register_taxonomy('product_category', 'product', $genre_args);


/**** REWRITE ****/

add_rewrite_rule(
        $productCategoryBaseSlug.'/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?product_category=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'top'
);


/**** CONTENT OF PERMALINK FUNCTION ****/
if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'product' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'product_category' );
        if( $terms ){
            //return str_replace( '%product_category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
            $post_link = str_replace('%product_category%', get_taxonomy_parents(array_pop($terms)->term_id, 'product_category', false, '/', true), $post_link);
            
            
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me about that ? I'm stuck for hours and can't find a solution :/

EDIT : As explained in comment below, i made a mistake in the custom post type declaration, a slash was missing, new code is :

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => $productCategoryBaseSlug.'/%product_category%',
    'with_front' => false
)
```

BUT NOW, th result is the following :

site.com/products = OK

site.com/products/page/2 = OK

site.com/products/category = OK

site.com/products/category/page/2 = BROKEN, Leads to site.com/page/2

site.com/products/category/product-name = OK

I'd live to read Milo's advice (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4771/milo) about this as he seems to be the real expert of rewrite rules !

Thank you

Comment: Further note : if i change the rewrite slug in the custom post type declaration to : 'slug' => $productCategoryBaseSlug.'/%product_category%' (added a slash before %product_category%) the single page is working fine but pagination is broken for categories :/

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know why but here is a working solution :

```
        $blogCategoryBaseSlug = 'articles';
        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => __( 'Blog Post', 'Post Type General Name', $this->text_domain ),
            'singular_name'         => __( 'Blog Post', 'Post Type Singular Name', $this->text_domain ),
            'menu_name'             => __( 'Blog Posts', $this->text_domain ),
            'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Blog Post', $this->text_domain ),
            'archives'              => __( 'Blog Post Archives', $this->text_domain ),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Blog Post:', $this->text_domain ),
            'all_items'             => __( 'All Blog Posts', $this->text_domain ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add Blog Post', $this->text_domain ),
            'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', $this->text_domain ),
            'new_item'              => __( 'New Blog Post', $this->text_domain ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Blog Post', $this->text_domain ),
            'update_item'           => __( 'Update Blog Post', $this->text_domain ),
            'view_item'             => __( 'View Blog Post', $this->text_domain ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search Blog Post', $this->text_domain ),
            'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', $this->text_domain ),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', $this->text_domain ),
            'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', $this->text_domain ),
            'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', $this->text_domain ),
            'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', $this->text_domain ),
            'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', $this->text_domain ),
            'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into Blog Post', $this->text_domain ),
            'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Blog Post', $this->text_domain ),
            'items_list'            => __( 'Blog Posts list', $this->text_domain ),
            'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Blog Posts list navigation', $this->text_domain ),
            'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter Blog Posts list', $this->text_domain ),
        );
        $args = array(
            'label'                 => __( 'Blog Post', $this->text_domain ),
            'description'           => __( 'Replacement for text post', $this->text_domain ),
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats', ),
            'taxonomies'            => array( 'blog_post_category', 'blog_post_tag'),
            'hierarchical'          => false,
            'public'                => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_in_menu'          => true,
            'menu_position'         => 5,
            'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
            'can_export'            => true,
            'has_archive'           => $blogCategoryBaseSlug,   
            'exclude_from_search'   => false,
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'capability_type'       => 'post',
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => $blogCategoryBaseSlug.'/%blog_post_category%',
                'with_front' => false
            )        
        );
        register_post_type( 'blogpost', $args );


        $genre_args = array( 
            'labels' => array(
                'name'=> __('Categories', 'taxonomy general name', $this->text_domain),
                'singular_name' => __('Category', 'taxonomy singular name', $this->text_domain),
                'search_items' => __('Search Categories', $this->text_domain),
                'popular_items' => __('Popular Categories', $this->text_domain),
                'all_items' => __('All Categories', $this->text_domain),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Category', $this->text_domain),
                'update_item' => __('Update Category', $this->text_domain),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Category', $this->text_domain),
                'new_item_name' => __('New Category Name', $this->text_domain),
                'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Seperate Categories with Commas', $this->text_domain),
                'add_or_remove_items' => __('Add or Remove Categories', $this->text_domain),
                'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose from Most Used Categories', $this->text_domain)
            ),  
            'public' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'with_front' => false,
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'slug' => $blogCategoryBaseSlug
            )        
        );
        register_taxonomy('blog_post_category', 'blogpost', $genre_args);

        add_rewrite_rule(
            $blogCategoryBaseSlug.'/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$',
            'index.php?blog_post_category=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
            'top'
        );

        add_rewrite_rule(
            $blogCategoryBaseSlug.'/(.+?)/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$',
            'index.php?blog_post_category=$matches[1]&blogpost=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]',
            'top'
        );
```

But there is still an issue concerning the rewrite rules ... So far, about everything is working :

site.com/articles= OK

site.com/articles/page/2 = OK

site.com/articles/category = OK

site.com/articles/category/page/2 = OK

site.com/articles/category/article-name = OK

But if i create a subcategory, it doesn'work :

site.com/articles/category/subcategory = 404 (looking for a post and not a sub category)

Is there any solution in the rewrite rules to fix that ?